# Has anyone else seen a message about processing slowness on the Elsevier editorial manager?

Tags: publications, elsevier

Seeing this message on the top of the editorial manager page. Does this mean the journal is overwhelmed with articles or does it simply mean the system is slow when loading pages? Not sure how to interpret it.

"Aries has detected slowness issues in EM/PM and users may experience some processing delays. Please know that work queues in the order received on the servers and while it may take some time to render your work will not be lost. We will share additional status updates as soon as possible."

Answer (score 1):

Aries is a private company that operates the journal management program [Editorial Manager](https://www.ariessys.com/software/editorial-manager/). Every journal has its own "Editorial Manager", configured with its settings.

The message sounds to me like Aries's servers hosting this journal's Editorial Manager is having issues. If so, it's obviously not ideal, but it's also why servers need to be maintained.